# Why does DVI-VGA adapter causes scren tearing?

Tags: display, vga, dvi, display-adapter, screen-tearing

What actually happens during conversion that may cause screen tearing? 
With HDMI output the image is stable but when I use the DVI-VGA connector to connect to my monitor I have pretty bad screen tearing.

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear, but I presume you have the option to connect the output of your PC to a display EITHER via HDMI OR via DVI-VGA:

HDMI has a built-in protocol that asks the display what refresh rates (video frequencies) it is capable of displaying.  The source (computer) then sends video at a refresh rate that the display can happily use.

DVI-VGA has many variants that, over time, were developed (from having no such protocol, to having a protocol almost similar to HDMI) until HDMI took over as the preferred connection.  If a display screen has tearing in the video content, it usually means the source is sending the video at a refresh rate that the display CANNOT happily use.  The solution is to manually change the refresh rate in the graphics card settings until the tearing is cured.